# Token not generate after login with angular-oauth2-oidc and getting in loop

Tags: angular14

```
import { AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
issuer: "http://www.google.com",
clientId: "dummyClientID",
responseType: "code",
redirectUri: "https://localhost:49409",
silentRefreshRedirectUri: "https://localhost:49409",
scope: "openid profile", // Ask offline_access to support refresh token refreshes
useSilentRefresh: false, // Needed for Code Flow to suggest using iframe-based refreshes
silentRefreshTimeout: 5000000, // For faster testing
timeoutFactor: 0.75, // For faster testing
sessionChecksEnabled: true,
showDebugInformation: false, // Also requires enabling "Verbose" level in devtools
clearHashAfterLogin: false, // https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-   oidc/issues/457#issuecomment-431807040,
logoutUrl: "https://ssoqa.premierinc.com/signout",
tokenEndpoint: "https://www.google.com/access_token",
};
```

URL:-
https://localhost:49409/?code=B8PobSeK4BxLMsnKf7urT5a6hpM&iss=https%3A%2F%2Fssoqa.premierinc.com%3A443%2Fsso%2Foauth2&state=bVV0eHBQdzY2NFpkNHh1WEItSndrQkNhSExLYnZNdlFuSzJjTy5lWnRCNUtF%3B%252F&client_id=oc_costaccounting_web_canextgen_np

Request Method:
GET

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.